# Dual Monitors need setting up after every reboot

Tags: windows-7, display, nvidia-graphics-card

My new [PC](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/product?cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en&product=5156927) has on-board video with DVI and VGA ports (both ports can be used at the same time).

I didn't have the correct VGA to DVI adaptor on hand so I installed my spare NVIDIA GeForce GT 230 video card.

Main monitor is on the NVIDIA and the extended desktop monitor is using the on-board video card.

Every time I reboot the machine my main monitor is upside down and the other monitor is off. I have to go through and set up each monitor every time using the NVIDIA control panel and Windows 7 control panel Display settings.

Answer (score 2):

This is a hardware conflict of some sort. HP's [specs](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c03050867&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&product=5156927#N66) for your PC says

> *Integrated video is not available if a graphics card is installed

Better get the adapter you need.